# ¿Podrian ayudarme con la importacion de un excel con laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite

Son dos tablas pero me manda este error al querer importar Y Son dos modelo los que estoy usando uno se llama usuariomodel y el otro iniciodesesionmodel

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id_inicio_sesion' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `usuarios` (`nombre`, `apellidos`, `genero`, `perfil`, `pais`, `estado`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Carlos, Morales, 0, 0, 1, 9, 2019-11-04 17:34:06, 2019-11-04 17:34:06))

este es mi IMPORTACIÓN

```
   public function model(array $row)
{

  $usu = new UsuarioModel([
        'nombre' => $row[0], 
        'apellidos' => $row[1],
        'genero' => $row[2],
        'perfil' => $row[3],
        'pais' => $row[4],
        'estado' => $row[5],


    ]);

    $ini = new InicioSesionModel([
        'email' => $row[6]
    ]);

    return $usu;
}
```

Mi CONTROLADOR

```
    public function cargaMasivaUsuarios(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
   Excel::import(new UsuariosImport,$file);
    return back()->with('message','Importacion de Usuarios Completada');

}
```

MI VISTA LA PARTE DE LOS BOTONES ES ESTA

```
<div>
<form name= "frmExcel" action="/cargaMasiva" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
@csrf
<input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
<button id="btnSubirExcel" class="uk-button-success" data-mph-file="strExcel" type="submit">Importar</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que te lanza, suele ocurrir cuando un campo de tu tabla no tiene un valor predeterminado y no es nulo. Revisa la estructura de tu tabla.
Intuyo que el campo `id_inicio_sesion` será la clave primaria de tu tabla. ¿Has revisado que sea también `AUTO_INCREMENT`?. Si no es necesario que lo sea, revisa que tenga un valor por defecto, ya que si no lo haces, cuando vayas a insertar datos en la tabla (tal como lo haces ahora, que no estás enviando ningún valor a ese campo), te dará error.